# Teamstudio XControl: Can I use Java Beans to override "Save" action?

Tags: xpages, teamstudio-unplugged

I am trying to use the `Teamstudio XControl` template for my project and I am facing the issue with saving computed fields. E.g. when I create a new document, it will be version "1". Same goes for "Status" as there is small workflow attached but many actions and corresponding "Status" need to be computed.

XControl template's save action is parsing the posted data. I want to avoid this but I am not sure how to do that from a modal window without using iFrames.

I am going to try it anyways but I thought of opening to the community in case someone has already tried this and want to share the ideas/issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment this is not something we support but I don't think it would be a difficult thing to do, with one caveat that it would only work when using the Domino server as Unplugged does not support Java Beans.

I'd suggest logging an issue on the GitHub project so that we can track it and prioritise for a future release.

https://github.com/teamstudio/xcontrols-domino

Matt

Comment: Hi Matt, I have logged an issue https://github.com/teamstudio/xcontrols-domino/issues/324 for the same.